# Upload Whole URL to MYSQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, parameters

I have to upload an URL to my table which has more than one parameter. So my PHP URL would be `http://localhost:8888/Thing/urlc.php?id=1&url=http://www.example.com/?hi=true&something=false`

As expected, the database only receives `http://www.example.com/?hi=true` because `&something=false` becomes a part of `http://localhost:8888/Thing/urlc.php`

How can I upload the whole URL (`http://www.example.com/?hi=true&something=false`) into the table

Comment: please encode url before. and decode it when you want to use it

Comment: How to encode it and decode it with javascript?

Comment: you can use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() to encode url in javascript